# Why do I have to compile JavaFX SceneBuilder?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I understand different platforms having different UI demands but why on earth do I have to download source and compile it on my own?  Why can I not just download a runnable version for my platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download an executable version: http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/

Comment: Netbeans apparently doesn't like this method: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=254857

Comment: I haven't tried it, but a comment by a NetBeans developer on the issue you linked, seems to indicate that NetBeans should work with the Gluon distribribution: "Currently, one must use either of the installers available from Oracle (archive) or Gluon. I have tested both of them on Windows (8.1, native installer) and Ubuntu (14.04, using Debian pkg) and they work fine."

Comment: You are correct.  Netbeans, at least on Windows, requires the installer.  You can't just point it to the executable jar.